# How can I get the drain apparatus out of a pedestal wash basin?

Tags: faucet, drain, replacement

I have successfully replaced two out of the three wash basin faucets in my house so far, but this one has me stumped:

[image: Pedestal Wash Basin]

As you can see from the picture, it's a pretty run-of-the-mill pedestal wash basin.  However, what this picture doesn't quite-so-adequately convey is how little clearance there is behind the pedestal to get a wrench in to drop the drain pipe:

[image: Tight clearance behind pedestal]

I'm hoping someone has some suggestions on how I can get a vise grip or an adjustable wrench behind this area?  The clearance is rather small and I don't think they make adjustable wrenches small enough but with big enough mouths to properly twist a trap nut.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the base of this pedestal without removing the sink first?

Comment: @BMitch there aren't any securing screws to the wall that I can see.  I've never installed a pedestal wash basin before, is it possible that the basin is just free-floating on top of the base?

The base is caulked to the bottom of the floor, I was avoiding removing that seal but I suppose if there's no other way, then that's the course I must take.

Comment: Caulk is easy to cut away and reapply. There's going to be something holding the sink to the wall, but it may or may not be designed to stay without the pedestal, so be ready to support it. And be careful not to scratch the floor.

Comment: Have you considered a strap wrench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have owned/installed a pedestal sink once before. The sink was mounted to the wall and the base slid into place after the plumbing was done. It was not a structural part and just covered the drain. Your's looks just like it.

Comment: Yes, upon further inspection the pedestal did indeed come off once I cut out the caulk from the floor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrench  specifically made for just this
You can pick on time at your local hardware store prices will very based on style and some made to fit a standard 3/8 ratchet drive and others with t handle  b sure and have a long enough extension to reach oh yeah the tool is called a basin wrench

Comment: This question was about the drain/trap, not the supply lines. Otherwise, yes, a basin wrench would be the best tool.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I do have a basin wrench already, as @bmitch says my problem was more about getting the trap off.

Answer (score -3):

there are "pedestal" wrenches...usually 1 1/4" or 1 1/2"

Comment: Can you provide a photo, or link to a "pedestal" wrench?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of blake's answer.